# Create a folder in Outlook: error 800A0401 - Expected End of Statement

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I created a .vbs file to create a folder in Outlook.

I copied most of the script out of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220308%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and get

> "Expected End of Statement" error code 800A0401

```
Option Explicit
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("Postini")

Wscript.Echo "Folder created"
Wscript.Quit
```

Never created a .vbs script before.

Windows 7 64-bit and Outlook 2010.  Running as local administrator.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This error is because you cannot dim variables as something in particular in VBS. Said more explicitly the "Dim" statement is used without defining the variable type in VBScript because all variables in VBScript are automatically of type Variant. If you attempt to Dim a variable as anything, it will throw an error.

Instead, you want:

```
Dim myNameSpace
Dim myFolder
Dim myNewFolder
```

Additionally, you seem to have just copied some VBA from Outlook and tried to run it as VBS.

VBscript does not know how to interpret `Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI")`.

You will need to also create an Outlook Application.

```
dim myOutlook
set myOUtlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Also, since you cannot provide references in VBS, you have to use late binding for any objects (which is why I used CreateObject.) So re-written your code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim myOutlook
Dim myNameSpace
Dim myFolder
Dim myNewFolder

set myOUtlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6) '6 is the value of olFolderInbox
Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("Postini")  
Wscript.Echo "Folder created"
Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: Oh, not sure if VBScript is case sensitive by you have `myOUtlook` in your first "set" line.

Comment: It's not, just like VBA technically isn't case sensitive. The difference is that in VBA the IDE will automatically update any capitalization inconsistencies.