# No experience with it but I need it

Tags: vbscript, vb6

```
Private Sub cmdtiehack_Click()     
    Dim hwnd
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Window name")          

    If hwnd = 0 Then         
        MsgBox "Program is not open"         
    Else         
        Dim Retval As Long     
        Retval = ShellExecute(Me.hwnd, "open", "5.exe", _     0, 0, SW_HIDE)     
        Delay 1     
        Retval = ShellExecute(Me.hwnd, "open", "6.exe", _     0, 0, SW_HIDE)     
    End If 
End Sub
```

I didn't use VB in past, but I can't see where's the error. Should I compile it or save like a .vbs just by using Notepad? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you help us with what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the _ from the lines. You would use them if you are splitting the line, but if you have it all on one line you don't need them.

So:

```
Retval = ShellExecute(Me.hwnd, "open", "5.exe", _
                      0, 0, SW_HIDE)
```

or

```
Retval = ShellExecute(Me.hwnd, "open", "5.exe", 0, 0, SW_HIDE)
```

would be ok.

**Edit Based on comment:**

Just had a look for the error code and I think this might help you:
[Expected end of statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803768/vbscript-800a0401-expected-end-of-statement)

Try removing the As Long.
Just as a side note, I would move the dim to the top of the function as well.

Comment: I'm still getting "Error: Expected end of statement". The error code is: 800A0401 Line:8 Char:20. Thanks for helping :D this is really the first time I've ever encountered and worked with VB.

Comment: Remove the As Long from the end of the Dim Retval.  Added some to the answer that goes into more details.

Comment: Buddy thanks a dozen the problem is solved. Hope you have a nice day :)